# How to verify that Java library (JAR file) works when used by Android project?

Tags: java, android, jar

We have a class library, written in Java (Standard Edition or MIDP 2.0, we have both variants), compiled to JAR file. There's nothing special in that library, mainly work with sockets (TCP and UDP) and threading.

Now we need to ensure, that this library will work on Android, and fix linkage problems (such as classes or methods missing on Android).

Is there a way to "validate" generic JAR file for Android without writing a complicated test case and running it on Android? I imagine something that I can pass the JAR to and it will tell me "could not load JAR - method X not found in class Y".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. If you have a JAR file which you want to check for basic compatibility with Android's libraries, you need to do the following:

1. Create an android project
2. Add a JAR file as an external JAR to the list of project libraries.
3. Attempt to build the project.

If the JAR references missing classes, you will get an error immediately during building.

Comment: Did you manage to get a list with the methods which did not work?

Comment: @Byron-LimTimothySteffan Sorry, that was so long ago that I don't remember :(

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to "validate" generic JAR file for Android without writing a complicated test case and running it on Android?

I would hope that somebody with your SO karma would not try to ship a JAR for Android without actually "running it on Android".

That being said, there's no good way that I can think of to perform your validation at the JAR level. However, if you pour your source code into an empty Android project, you will get compile errors if you refer to classes or methods that do not exist.

Comment: Our experience of porting the code to various platforms says that the first thing to do is some kind of static analysis, i.e. the code should be analyzed for possible incompatibilities and linkage issues before the runtime tests are written. It doesn't make sense to test the code that would be broken for that platform from the very beginning.

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp: So, pour your source code into an empty Android project, and you will get compile errors if you refer to classes or methods that do not exist.

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp: As I wrote, there's no good way that I can think of to perform your validation at the JAR level.

Comment: JFYI: I've found the solution I was looking for and I've posted it as an answer above.